# HTML Send button

Tags: javascript, html

[HTML Button that I create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xi0O.jpg)
I wanted to know if there is something for an HTML button, simulate that the ENTER key was pressed. Since I need a button to send an automatic chat in which I am working. I was able to implement the button, although it still does not perform any action. The messages are sent by pressing the ENTER key, so I wanted to find a way to simulate that action. Thank you

```
var fncTxMessageKeydown = function (e) {
            e = window.event || e;
            var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

            if (keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    e.returnValue = false;
                }

                var message = elements.txMessage.value.toString().trim();

                if (message!=""){
                    if (gotUid==true) {
                        EngtChat.sendMessage(message);
                        elements.txMessage.value = "";
                    }
                    else{
                        //show initialization alert and reconnect socket
                        document.getElementsByClassName("engt-sheet-header-with-presence")[0].style.padding="7px";
                        socket.disconnect();
                        socket.connect();

                    }
                }   
                return false;
            }
        };
        if (elements.txMessage != undefined) {
            elements.txMessage.onkeydown = fncTxMessageKeydown;
```

Comment: Usually pressing "return" in a text input will invoke the submit button in the same form.  What have you tried and how is it not working?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Search with "onKeyPress enter" keyword

Comment: Create a button inside the block where the TEXTAREA is, and it appeared. But it has not registered any action.

Comment: @SantiagoRuffino Is it a submit button?

Comment: Add the code snippet where you use the ENTER button. And attach the HTML image where I put the SEND button

Comment: Why the downvote?